# How to add an element to another one(instead of using selector)

Tags: javascript, dom

I found in [Document](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add) that I can create an element and add another one to it like:

```
var sel = document.createElement("select");
var opt1 = document.createElement("option");
var opt2 = document.createElement("option");

opt1.value = "1";
opt1.text = "Option: Value 1";

opt2.value = "2";
opt2.text = "Option: Value 2";

sel.add(opt1, null);
sel.add(opt2, null);
```

But when I tried to apply it to practice, this method doesn't work, `newUser` was not added to `newDiv` successfully:

```
function createOnEle(imgSrc, user, extract) {
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var newUser = document.createElement("span");

  newUser.textContent = user;

  newDiv.add(newUser);

}
```

It seems that `add` method doesn't work for `div` and `span`, if this is true, how to achieve it? Otherwise, Where did I wrong?

Comment: There's an [*Option* constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option), you can do `sel.add(new Option('Option: value 1', '1'), null)` and save yourself some typing. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `.add` is a method of `select-element` which is used to add an `option-element` to it.
>   Refer [**HTMLSelectElement.add()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add)

Use [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

> *The **Node.appendChild()** method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node.*

```js
function createOnEle(user) {
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var newUser = document.createElement("span");
  newUser.textContent = user;
  newDiv.appendChild(newUser);
  document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
}
createOnEle('RogB :)')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   function createOnEle(imgSrc, user, extract) {
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var newUser = document.createElement("span");

  newUser.textContent = user;

  newDiv.innerHTML=newUser;

}
```

This should also work as per your requirement .